# smalltalk singleton pattern: how do I initialize the instance variables?

Tags: singleton, smalltalk, instance-variables

I'm having trouble in getting the singleton pattern to initialize a instance variable in smalltalk. (here is a [link to another implementation](http://www.eli.sdsu.edu/courses/spring01/cs635/notes/singleton/singleton.html#slide7) for clarification)

this is what I have:

```
new

^UniqueInstance ifNil: [UniqueInstance := self basicNew.
                        UniqueInstance: instanceVar := Object new. ].
```

that last line (UniqueInstance: instanceVar := Object new.) doesn't work, but that's basically what I need to do: instantiate instanceVar as an Object before returning UniqueInstance back to the caller.

Notice that this 'new' method is used as a classinstantiation, and that libraries is a instance variable of UniqueIsntance (the isntance of the wanted class).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try simpler:

```
YourClass class>>singleton

       UniqueInstance ifNil: [UniqueInstance := self basicNew initialize].
       ^UniqueInstance
```

then on instance side of your class implement an appropriate #initialize method, for example:

```
YourClass>>initialize

          someInstvar := someInitalValue.
         ^self
```

**Update:**: Name of the class method accessing the singleton varies, it can be #default, #current, or #singleton. I mostly use later.

Comment: you might want to also add "super initialize." depending on your house rules about initialization...

Comment: Another syntax trick that I often use is possible because #ifNil: returns the receiver if it's not nil.  So you can do the whole method in one line: "^UniqueInstance ifNil: [UniqueInstance := self basicNew initialize]"

Comment: And while developing, you probably want a YourClass>>reset UniqueInstance := nil