# correctly using a singleton pattern in seaside/smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

I'm a learning Smalltalk and developing an application in Seaside.

The first part of the application will be the so called is administration side. In this part I can define/manage items users of the application are allowed to choose from. All items defined will be the same for all users. So I have created a class called sportsController.

I have used a singleton pattern as defined here: [smalltalk singleton pattern: how do I initialize the instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438729/smalltalk-singleton-pattern-how-do-i-initialize-the-instance-variables).

On the class side I have:

```
default
 ^ Default ifNil: [ Default := self new ]
```

On the instance I have:

```
initialize 
    sports := OrderedCollection new.
```

and

```
sports
^ sports
```

When I call the view I have:

```
manageSports
view := SportsAdminView new model: SportsController default
```

The method 'manageSports' is called as a callback. When I run the view the following code  is executed:

```
renderContentOn: html 
html anchor
    callback: [self addSport];
     with: 'Add new sport'.
html
    unorderedList: [self model sports
            do: [:value | html
                    listItem: [self renderSport: value on: html]]].
```

When I run this #sports is nil. So there is a MessageNotUnderstood notification. So I'm probably doing something wrong; what? That said is there a better way of doing this? The main objective is to create class that used by all sessions a like.

BTW For the moment I don't do persistence yet, other then in the image. 'Real' persistence will be dealt with later. For the moment I need to be able to add data to develop the customer side of the application.

Comment: What happens when you print: `SportsController default sports` in a workspace? As far as i see, this should answer an empty OrderedCollection - so the problem is not with your Singleton class but elsewhere?

Comment: I ran the following in the workspace `SportsController default sports` with print it. The answers was nil. I will further investigate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you called `SportsController default` the first time before you added the `initialize` method to the instance side? In this case your `initialize` method was never called.

So you can call it once from the workspace via `SportsController default initialize`, or you set the class variable `Default` to `nil` and try it again.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I have no idea how this could have happened. Now it works. I added a method reset and ran that.