# Singleton pattern for multi-processing on Pharo 10.0 ( Smalltalk )

Tags: design-patterns, multiprocessing, singleton, smalltalk, pharo

I can't pass the test below.

```
"SingletonTest"
testCurrent
        
    | semaphore object1 object2 |
    Singleton initialize.

    semaphore := Semaphore new.

    [ 
    Processor yield.
    object1 := Singleton current.
    semaphore signal ] fork.

    object2 := Singleton current.

    semaphore wait.
    self assert: object1 identicalTo: object2
```

Here is my first implementation which is failed.

```
"Singleton class"
current

    Transcript
        show: 'start';
        cr. 
    current := current ifNil: [ 
                   Transcript
                       show: 'creating..';
                       cr.
                   self new ].
    ^ current

initialize

    isProcessing := false.
    current := nil
```

I have tried to pass the test by using a naive exclusion control but the result was same.
Here is my second implementation.

```
"Singleton class"
current

    [ isProcessing ] whileTrue: [  ].
    isProcessing := true.
    current := current ifNil: [ 
                   (Delay forSeconds: 2) wait.
                   self new ].
    isProcessing := false.
    ^ current

initialize

    isProcessing := false.
    current := nil
```

How can I pass the test?
I'm looking forward to hearing your tips!

Answer (score 3):

Your code for `#'initialize'` resets the `current` so that is why you are getting two different values. Try deleting all but the first call to `#'initialize'`.

Note also that race conditions are tricky things. In the first implementation of `#'current'` you have a two-second delay in which you could create two instances of `Singleton`. In the second implementation you could have two threads find `isProcessing` to be `false` and find `current` to be `nil` so both wait for two seconds and create it.

To guarantee that you get only one instance, you should set up the instance during your setup code or protect the creation with a `Semaphore`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have added the code `#'initialize'`. I don't know how to use `Semaphore` in this situation. Could you please show me a sample code?

Comment: Oh. I pass the test in the second implementation.. But I don't think this naive implementation is the best. I still want you to show your code.

Comment: Here is my code. https://github.com/yujihamaguchi/little-smalltalker-filetree/tree/master/Q060-Singleton.package

Comment: I understand that the test now passes. What changes did you make to have that happen? What was the motivation for using a `Delay`? Is there any reason you don't just follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438729/smalltalk-singleton-pattern-how-do-i-initialize-the-instance-variables) example?

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake. I changed my assert to like `object1 indenticalTo: object1` (same object!!) temporary. So I pass the test incorrectly.

Comment: Your suggested example is same to my first implementation above. By the implementation the test is failed. Transcript log is `start. creating.. start. creating..`. This means `current` method create two instance, so object1 is not same to object2.

Comment: If you remove the `Transcript show: ...` code does it work? I suspect that you are getting a context switch during the I/O. Try something like:
`current isNil ifTrue: [current := self new. Transcript show: 'Creating..'].`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have resolved this issue by using Mutex( and `critical:` message ). And I have added another test. Please check that. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any evidence that you have responded to my comment from yesterday (the 9th).